# How can I tell which module/script has just run this script in Python?

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I have a module called `detector.py`, and I want to import the module `Vimba` into it only if `detector.py` is being imported by `experiment.py`. Is this importer-specific conditional importing possible?

If I import this module (`detector.py`) into a different module, say `test.py`, I don't want to try to import `Vimba`.

I've tried checking `__name__` to see if it tells me who my importer is, but I only get the general module path of this module `project.detection.detector`.

Comment: This is a real code smell. A module should work the same no matter how it's being used. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Fair point Barmar. I'm running CI testing (through GH Actions) on a module (detector.py) which requires Vimba for some functionality. It seems that Vimba is not installable via the command line so I'm trying to test the detector.py functionality that doesn't require Vimba. In order to do this, I need to import the detector into my test, but it'll throw an error without the Vimba module, hence the conditional import.
Please let me know if you have a better solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.modules` to check if a module has been imported.

```py
import sys

if 'experiment' in sys.modules:
    import Vimba
```